# Show the subspace $\textrm{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is not closed in $\ell^2$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

How to show the subspace $\textrm{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ where $e_n=(\delta_{nk})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is not closed in $\ell^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider 
$$
x=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}e_n
$$

Comment: I'll try.. I was trying with $$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e_i}{\sqrt{i}}$$ but I got nowhere.. Thanks

Comment: Q1. Do you see why $x$ does not belong to that subspace? Q2. Do you see which vectors one must choose to get arbitrary close to $x$?

Comment: Another important thing: $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ does not belong to $\ell_2$. Using $2^n$ in the denominator solves this problem.

Comment: I don't know why there are so many restrictions to edit the coments \o/... I wanted to say: As to Q2 it suffices taking the sequence $$(x_n)=(x_k^{(n)})_{k\in\mathbb N}$$ where $$x_k^{(n)}=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
1/k&\textrm{if}&k\leq n\\
0&\textrm{if}&k>n
\end{array}\right.,$$ right? As to $Q1$, I can't see why it is not in that subspace, maybe you can help me @Norbert..

Comment: A1. All elements of that subspace have only finitely many non-zero entries while $x$ doesn't. A2. see answer of Serios

Comment: Thanks for the help @Norbert.. I did a proof using your ideas:

Comment: Consider $$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e_n}{2^n}.$$ Let us show $$x\in \overline{\textrm{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb N\}}$$ but $$x\not\in \textrm{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb N\}.$$ In fact, consider the sequence $$(x_n)=(x_k^{(n)})_{k\in\mathbb N},$$ where $$x_k^{(n)}=\left\{\begin{array}{lll} \displaystyle \frac{1}{2^k}&\textrm{if}&k\leq n\\ 0&\textrm{if}&k>n\end{array}\right..$$

Comment: Note that $x_k^{(n)}\in \textrm{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $$\displaystyle \|x_n-x\|_2^2=\sum_{k=0}^\infty |x_k^{(n)}-x_k|^2\\
=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |x_k^{(n)}|^2\\
=\sum_{k=n+1}\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\\
=\sum_{\ell=2n+2}\frac{1}{2^\ell}\to 0,$$ when $n\to \infty$ for $$\displaystyle \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^\ell}<+\infty.$$ Therefore $$x\in \overline{\textrm{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb N\}}.$$

Comment: Now I don't know how to write formally that $$x\not\in \textrm{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb N\},$$ any tip?

Comment: Assume $x\in\mathrm{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, then $x=\sum\limits_{k=1}^M c_k e_k $ for some $M\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\{c_k:k\in\{1,\ldots,M\}\}\subset\mathbb{R}$. Hence $x_i=0$ for all $i>M$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X= \text{span} \{e_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and $x \in \ell^2$. Then $\displaystyle x= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{+ \infty} x_ie_i$ and $\displaystyle ||x||_2^2= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{+ \infty} |x_i|^2 <+ \infty$. So, for $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N \geq 0$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i \geq n} |x_i|^2 < \epsilon$. Let $\displaystyle y = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_ie_i$. Then $y \in X$ and $\displaystyle ||x-y||_2^2= \sum\limits_{i \geq N+1} |x_i|^2 < \epsilon$.

You deduce that $X$ is dense in $\ell^2$. Therefore, $X$ is closed in $\ell^2$ iff $X= \ell^2$. But $\displaystyle z= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{+ \infty} z_ie_i$ belongs to $X$ iff $\{i \geq 1 : z_i \neq 0\}$ is finite; therefore, $X \subsetneq \ell^2$.

Comment: After concluding the space is dense it's easy to show it is not closed: its dimension is countable whereas $\ell_2$'s dimension is not.